# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ﬁ (U+FB01)

Tags: input-encodings, compilation-error

TexStudio underlines in red an excerpt in which there are some double quotation marks, giving the error above.

I use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U+FB01 is an fi ligature which should never be in your source file. So best would be to edit the input and replace it by `fi` but failing that

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
```

should work.

Comment: (Just thought I'd mention) I've encountered f-ligatures in source code from time to time. I think it's usually the result of the author copy and pasting from another source (such as a PDF created by TeX).

Comment: Exactly! This was the case! @Nicola Talbot