# While copy from pdf file and pasting in tex file getting inputenc error

Tags: input-encodings

Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ﬂ (U+FB02)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...me, but the order of characters is shufﬂ

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This kind of thing happens when you copy content form a formatted document, like a pdf. The unicode chanracter `ﬂ` (notice it is *one single* character) is not supprted. remove it and type `fl` instead.

Comment: i am new to latex.
can you tell me how to remove it?

Comment: Just find the `ﬂ` character in the code and erase it. The error message probably says something like `l.XX shufﬂ`. The `XX` is the number of the line in which the character is.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417749

Comment: Nicola Talbot's answer is the good one, but too much copy paste smell  like a kind of plagiarism ;-)